# How do I achieve the effect of converting a super class object to a subclass object?

Tags: java, inheritance, type-conversion, jgrapht

I have a library which builds a HashMap using a datatype X which it takes as input. It is the JGraphT library. Now, I have two types of X. Y and Z. So X is a super class. Y and Z are subclasses of X. Now X is a vertex. Y and Z are specific kinds of vertices.

Now, when I build a graph in JGraphT and and get the source Vertex of any edge in a graph, I get it as datatype X. I want to convert it to datatype Y and Z, but simple paranthesized type conversion won't work. I understand that you cannot convert that way from superclass objects to subclass objects. But is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the result of the call is actually an instance of `Y` or `Z` you can use `instanceof`.

```
X x = someCall();
if (x instanceof Y) {
    Y y = (Y)x;
    y.doSomething();
}
else
if (x instanceof Z) { ... }
```

If the returned x is just an X and not actually a Y or Z, then you would need to create your own Y or Z based on the data in X (perhaps via a constructor that takes an X instance as an arg).

Comment: mmm i put your same example :( f.ck! xD

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert it to datatype Y and Z, but simple parenthesized type conversion won't work.

Presumably "simple parenthesized type conversion" means something like this:

```
X myX = ...
Y myY = (Y) myX;
```

That is called a "*typecast*".

It says "if `myX` is really an instance of `Y`, then assign it to `myY`".  The typecast will fail (with a runtime exception<sup>1</sup>) if the object that `myX` refers to is NOT an instance of `Y`.

> I understand that you cannot convert that way from superclass objects to subclass objects.

If by "convert", you mean something *different* to the above typecast, then that is correct.

> But is there any way to achieve this?

There is no general way to "convert" an object to a type that is different to its real type or a supertype of its real type.  Such a "conversion" can only be done by writing some method to do the task, and it *necessarily* entails creating a distinct new object.  Whether this is sensible (or even possible) depends on the application.

(For instance, if the instance represents a node in a graph, then a "conversion" that creates a new object will give you something that the other nodes of the graph don't refer to.  That is liable to break something.)

---

<sup>1 - You can use `instanceof` tests to guard against the exceptions, but this won't allow you to typecast an object to a type that it ... isn't a member of.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would be to add a static method to Y and Z that does what you want:

```
    class Y extends X {
    ...
            public static Y toYType(X original) {
                ....
            }
    ...
    }
```

Anyway you can't "convert" the same object to a subclass, think about this: Y is a specialized type of X, maybe with extra fields; if you could "convert" X to Y, how should this extra fields be filled up? You need to explicitly create a new object Y

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that you cannot convert that way from superclass objects to subclass objects.

That is right, this is called `downcasting` and is allowed and safe only in certain circumstances.
Example of valid downcast:

```
X x = (X)new Y();  // x is the result of upcasting of an object 
                   // of type Y in the 1st place

Y y = (Y)x;        // Allowed and safe in this specific case.
```

One way to achieve what you meant, is to implement copy constructors:

```
class X {
    public int x, y, z;

    public X() {

    }

    // Here the default copy cstor
    public X(X src_x) {
        this.x = src_x.x;
        this.y = src_x.y;
        this.z = src_x.z;

        System.out.println("Cstor base copy called");
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    public int u;

    // Here the copy cstor: sets x, y, z from x to this(type Y)
    public Y(X x) {
        super(x);
    }

}

class Z extends X {
    public int v;

    // Here the copy cstor
    public Z(X x) {
        super(x);
    }

}
```

Then you can do:

```
X x = new X();
x.x = 1;
x.y = 2;
x.z = 3;

Y y = new Y(x);
```

But it is quite far from a simple typecast...